# Initilizing value for a const data

Tags: c++, visual-c++, qt, qt4

Following code is in my c++ class

```
static const  QString ALARM_ERROR_IMAGE ;
```

i want to initilize

```
ALARM_ERROR_IMAGE          = "error.png";
```

Is it possible to initilize `error.png` to `static const QString ALARM_ERROR_IMAGE` 
Want to keep it inside class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static variable of a class have to be defined explicitly in the namespace scope only once (irrespective of wheter they are further cv qualified or not).

In the .cpp file (e.g in `<ClassName>.cpp`), in the global namespace (assuming your class is in global namespace), define it as follows (assuming an appropriate constructor exists in QString)

NB: I missed 'const' in the definition below

```
const QString <ClassName>::ALARM_ERROR_IMAGE = "error.png";
```

> $9.4.2/2 - "The declaration of a
>   static data member in its class
>   definition is not a definition and may
>   be of an incomplete type other than
>   cv-qualified void. The definition for
>   a static data member shall appear in a
>   namespace scope enclosing the member’s
>   class definition. In the definition at
>   namespace scope, the name of the
>   static data member shall be qualified
>   by its class name using the ::
>   operator."

Comment: so can i write it outside the class like how u said

Comment: My class is abc.cpp and is it possible to write   QString <abc>::ALARM_ERROR_IMAGE = "error.png"; if i do  like this will be constant

Comment: You need to write as QString abc::ALARM_ERROR_IMAGE = "error.png";. Yes, once it is initialized, it can not be modified. It is constant.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to keep inside.
Only const static integral data members are allowed to initialized inside a class or struct.