# How to keep static const variable as a member of a class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, qt, qt4

I want to keep a static const variable as a member of class.
Is it possible to keep and how can i initilize that variable.

Some body helped by saying this

```
 QString <ClassName>::ALARM_ERROR_IMAGE = "error.png";
```

[Initilizing value for a const data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698446/initilizing-value-for-a-const-data)

I tried like this

in CPP class i write

```
static  QString ALARM_WARNING_IMAGE ;
```

In constructor i write

```
ALARM_WARNING_IMAGE        = "warning.png";
```

But not working... Please help by giving some hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the basic idea:

```
struct myclass{
 //myclass() : x(2){}      // Not OK for both x and d
 //myclass(){x = 2;}       // Not OK for both x and d
 static const int x = 2;   // OK, but definition still required in namespace scope
                               // static integral data members only can be initialized
                               // in class definition
     static const double d;    // declaration, needs definition in namespace scope,
                               // as double is not an integral type, and so is
                               // QSTRING.
     //static const QString var; // non integral type
};

const int myclass::x;             // definition
const double myclass::d = 2.2;    // OK, definition
// const QString myclass::var = "some.png";

int main(){
}
```

Comment: Any reason for commenting out `var`? That seems to imply that it's not valid, when it is.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Because I don't have QString definition with me.

Answer (score 10):

Outside of any function in the source file write:

```
const QString ClassName::ALARM_WARNING_IMAGE = "warning.png";
```

This construction also works:

```
const QString ClassName::ALARM_WARNING_IMAGE("warning.png");
```

Header:

```
class ClassName {
  static const QString ALARM_WARNING_IMAGE;
};
```

Also, don't write anything in the constructor. This would initialize the static variable everytime ClassName is instantiated. This does not work, because the variable is const and a bad idea so to speak. consts can only be set once during declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`QString ClassName::ALARM_WARNING_IMAGE = "warning.png";`

Comment: Any need to declare inside C++ class

Comment: If you make it constant, you have to mark BOTH the *declaration* (in the class) and the *definition* (which is what this answer shows) as `const`.

Comment: see my answer. it should be detailed enough to see how it's working

Answer (score 0):

Only const static integral data members are allowed to initialized inside a class or struct.